# Increasing speed of objects over time using p5js

Tags: javascript

I am playing around with p5js and wanted to create a simple game where the main goal is to jump over objects that are incoming from the right side of the screen.

So, pretty basic idea.

Everything appears to be working so far, however, I would like to increase the speed of objects that keep incoming either over a period of time or after an X amount of objects have passed. Currently, I am storing the objects into an array and looping through them. 
Speed is determined by `this.speed` in the `Pipe()` function.

In order to show you what I mean, you can check the running version here. ( I had to put all functions into one file in order for this to work online)

[FOR GAME CLICK HERE](https://jsbin.com/vudejiyele/edit?html,js,output)

(the game is played by pressing and/or holding the `UP_ARROW`)

I was trying to update `this.speed` from the draw function, but I wasn't able to keep `this.speed` persistent.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably need to make a global speed variable so that all pipes are affected accordingly.
A suggestion would be to create an interval which increments `speed` and then assign that to `this.x` within the update function of the Pipe object.

```
this.update = function() {
    this.x -= speed;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/fodekizohi/1/edit?html,js,output